# JavaScript adding multiple attributes from object dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, dynamic

I have created an object with a list of attributes to add to html tag. I wanted to add these to a created element. 
This is the code

> var up = {class:"upt", name:"positive_use",type:"text"};
>
> createtextarea = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");

How to add these objects to the element.
And how do you add more than one dynamically.

Comment: You add them one-by one using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute` like this

```js
var up={class:"upt", name:"positive_use",type:"text"};

let createtextarea = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');

createtextarea.setAttribute('class', up.class);
createtextarea.innerHTML = "TEST TEXT AREA";
createtextarea.setAttribute('name', up.name);
createtextarea.setAttribute('type', up.type);

document.body.appendChild(createtextarea);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a foreach loop over the object keys of up and then use the setAttribute function.

```
Object.keys(up).forEach((k) => createtextarea.setAttribute(k, up[k])) // k would be the "class","name","type") in every iteration.
```

Comment: Yeah thank you. I redid the same with a function to create and add this